# How to create a sankey diagram in R showing changes over time for the same node?

Tags: r, time, sankey-diagram

I am trying to create a Sankey diagram of my data.

For each therapy, individuals are followed over time. I would like to have one node "Therapy" (categorical variable with different therapy names) repeated over time and x axis accounting for the time. Any ideas? I really appreciate any help.

This is what I have tried to so far:

```
### install and load packages
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("ggforce")

# load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(ggforce)

### read dataset
dataset_new <- read_excel("Made_up_dataset_new.xlsx")
df_new <- as.data.frame(dataset_new)

df_new$Unit <- 1

df_sankey <- df_new[c("Therapy", "Frequency", "Continuous_time","Unit")]

# transform dataframe into appropriate format
df_sankey <- gather_set_data(df_sankey, 1:3)

# define axis-width / sep parameters once here, to be used by each geom layer in the plot
aw <- 0.1
sp <- 0.1

ggplot(df_sankey, 
       aes(x = x, id = id, split = y, value = Unit)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Therapy), alpha = 0.3, 
                     axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = "white", 
                            angle = 0, size = 3,
                            axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  theme_minimal()
```

But the result is not what I want because time is compacted on the y axis, and not on the x axis, if that makes sense?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190995/discussion-on-question-by-daniela-rodrigues-how-to-create-a-sankey-diagram-in-r).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you have several options. The first solution which worked for me was `ggplot` / `geom_flow`:

```
# requires(ggplot2)
# requires(ggalluvial)

# faking the data for 20 patients
set.seed(42)
individual <- as.character(rep(1:20,each=5))
timeperiod <- paste0(rep(c(0, 18,36,54,72),20),"_week")
therapy <- factor(sample(c("Etanercept", "Infliximab", "Rituximab",  "Adalimumab","Missing"), 100, replace=T))
d <- data.frame(individual, timeperiod, therapy)
head(d)

# Plotting it
ggplot(d, aes(x = timeperiod, stratum = therapy, alluvium = individual, fill = therapy, label = therapy)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "rightleft", color = "darkgray") +
  geom_stratum() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("Treatment across observation period")
```

[image]

The argument `stat = "alluvium"` in `geom_flow` should allow to track individual patients, But if you want, you can also merge the flows:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = timeperiod, stratum = therapy, alluvium = individual, fill = therapy, label = therapy)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
  geom_flow(color = "darkgray") +
  geom_stratum() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("Treatment across observation period")
```

[image]

**EDIT 1**: If you want that for some patients the flow is discontinued (e.g. therapy has finished), you can easily do it by setting these patients as NAs:

```
# setting 3 pantients as NA for the last timepoint
d[which(d$individual==3 & d$timeperiod=="72_week"), ]["therapy"] <- NA 
d[which(d$individual==6 & d$timeperiod=="72_week"), ]["therapy"] <- NA 
d[which(d$individual==9 & d$timeperiod=="72_week"), ]["therapy"] <- NA 

# making the plot:
ggplot(d, aes(x = timeperiod, stratum = therapy, alluvium = individual, fill = therapy, label = therapy)) +
scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "rightleft", color = "darkgray") + 
geom_stratum(alpha=0.75) +
theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
ggtitle("Treatment across observation period")
```

[image]
Now, to be honest, also the `networkD3` worked, but I just didn´t manage to make it look good enough.

**EDIT 2**:

- You can also use `geom_alluvium` instead of `geom_flow`. The main (visual) difference between them is that in `geom_flow` the color of flow is inherited from the neighboring nodes (either source or target). In `geom_alluvium` it is instead inherited from the first node - e.g. flow *will not* change color at the when passing through the nodes.
- If you want to combine the chart with another plot, the easiest way would seem to use `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`.